# Can I check if a scanned string is equal to a character?

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{   char code[15];
    
    printf("\n\tEnter the code >>> ");
    scanf("%s", code);
    if(code=="checkif")
        printf("\n\t Correct");
    else
        printf("\n\tIncorrect");
}
```

Comment: you want `strcmp()`.  But some may suggest the `strncmp()` function as it compares not more than n characters.  The `man` pages are excellent for these C apis ( `man strcmp` from the command line ).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You use the function **strcmp** exist in the header **#include <string.h>** to compare between two strings

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   char code[15];

    printf("\n\tEnter the code >>> ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", code);
    if(strcmp(code,"checkif")==0)
    printf("\n\t Correct");
    else
    printf("\n\tIncorrect");
}
```